# Exportar bd oracle por comando

Tags: oracle-11g

Estoy tratando de migrar una bd oracle, por comandos, ya que el gestor que usa la maquina,

Ddbeaver, no encuentro la opcion de exportar bd oracle.

me creé una carpeta en c, donde voy hacer la exportacion

pero cuando intento luego por sqlplus consola, ejecutar esta linea de codigo para vincular el directorio.
aparentemente no hace nada.

```
create directory backup as 'C:\backuporacle'
2|
```

cuando ejecuto esa linea, debajo me aparece un 2... y no se que significa ese dos.
he intentado colocar contraseña... darle ENTER, pero no hace nada, no me sale el mensaje de

directory created
que me deberia salir.
muchas gracias si alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: falta `;` y la query que estas ejecutando solo  crea un alias para la ruta `C:\backuporacle` ahora oracle entiende que `backup` es esa ruta... para crear un backup debes hacer un `exp o exdp`

Comment: No olvides colocar `;` al final...

Comment: gracias, este era mi error.